# Request to open question about writing a good comment

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How to write a Stack Exchange comment?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42641/how-to-write-a-stack-exchange-comment) was recently put on hold as too broad, but how is it more broad than [How do you write a Stack Exchange answer?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33613/how-do-you-write-a-stack-exchange-answer?rq=1)? If anything, my question on comment technique was narrower as I gave a list of use cases for comments and a description of what I was looking for in an answer.

Furthermore, I think the fact that the answerer managed to thoroughly answer every single aspect of the question with 7 headings 9 paragraphs 2 quotes and a bullet list of 5 sentences further shows it wasn't insurmountably broad.

Or should I remove my bullet list, which I felt narrowed the scope of the question, in order to remove the "asking multiple questions" aspect?

If you still feel the question is too broad, do you have any suggestions on how to narrow it?

Comment: Agreed. I have a hard time understanding what is too broad and what isn't on this site. If how to write an answer is ok, how to write a comment should be too.

Comment: I voted to reopen. It takes five votes. Three more to go.

Comment: I wasn't on SE when the other question came up.  I VTC your question but not because it was too broad (the system seems to take the most popular reason as *the* reason).  I said it belonged on Meta.  I thought the question itself was fine.

Comment: Yes.  But it takes 5 people to close a question and this is the opinion of 1 person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been reopened.